# Смысл использования HashMap при наличии риска коллизий

Tags: java, byte, java-hashmap

Здравствуйте,

недавно пробовал использовать `HashMap` следующим образом: есть регистр состоящий из 2ух байтов это адрес и содержание этого регистра из 2ух байтов.

К примеру по адресу `0xF1 0x15` (младший, старший байт) регистр содержит данные `0x12 0x45`  (младший, старший байт).

Т.к. адрес состоит из двух байт то всего может быть 256*256 = 65536 регистров. 
С помощью `HashMap` создаю базу данных примерно следующего вида:

```
          HashMap<String,Data2BytesCell> mDataBase = new HashMap<>();
           mDataBase.put( Byte.toString( (byte) 0xF1 ) + 
                      Byte.toString( (byte) 0x15 ), 
                          new data2BytesCell((byte) 0x12, (byte) 0x45 );
```

Ключ я создаю в виде строки из двух байтов, здесь в частности "F115". По этому же ключю аналогично извлекаю значение регистра.

В результате создал 65536 элементов, но когда начал проверять эти элементы на коллизии, то их оказалось очень много. Т.е. в регистре должно содержать одно значение по данному адресу, а он выводит совершенно другое.

Какой смысл использовать такое не надежное хранилище как `HashMap` когда такая большая вероятность коллизий ? Может я его ни так использую ? Или использую не по назначению ?

Заранее большое спасибо всем за ответы.

Для конкретики приведу более детальный код с методами:

```
                // в классе создается объект базы данных
                 HashMap<String,Data2BytesCell> mDataBase = new HashMap<>();


              // Описание метода записи данных по адресу.
              //  Данные заносятся в базу по данному адресу
              // (является ключом). 
              public void setData(byte lBAddress, byte hBAddress, byte lBData, byte hBData){
                      mDataBase.put(Byte.toString(lBAddress) + Byte.toString(hBAddress),
                        new Data2BytesCell( lBData, hBData ) );
              }

             // Данные считываются с определенного адреса (ключа).
             // Возвращает массив из 2 байт (данные)
              public byte[] getData(byte lBAddress, byte hBAddress){
                   Data2BytesCell data2BytesCell = mDataBase.get( Byte.toString(lBAddress) + Byte.toString(hBAddress) );


                    return data2BytesCell.getData();
              }
```

Приведу также метод проверки на коллизии:

```
      public void validateCollisions(){
    // Здесь в данные data2BytesCell в 2 байта записываются значение    
    // адреса. Т.е. например в регистр с адресом 0х01 0х02 (ключ "0102")
    // записывается значение 0х01 и 0х02.
    // Теперь когда я захочу считать значение по адресу  0х01 0х02
    // (ключ "0102") я должен на выходе получить массив из двух элементов
    // 0х01 0х02. Аналогично заполняется регистры для остальных 256х256
    // адресов.
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 256; j++){
            Data2BytesCell data2BytesCell = new Data2BytesCell( (byte) i, (byte) j );
            mDataBase.put( Byte.toString( (byte) i ) + Byte.toString( (byte) j ), data2BytesCell);

        }
    }

    // Здесь идет проверка берем регистр с адресом 0х01 0х02 
    // (ключ "0102") извлекаем с помощью get извлекаем массив из двух 
    // байт если первый элемент равен 0х01, а второй 0х02, то все норм,
    // если нет, то выводим ошибку коллизия.
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 256; j++){
            Data2BytesCell data2BytesCell = mDataBase.get(Byte.toString( (byte) i ) + Byte.toString( (byte) j));
            byte lbHb[] = data2BytesCell.getData();

            if (lbHb[0] != (byte)i || lbHb[1] != (byte)j ){
                 Log.e(TAG, "Collision in: i = " + Integer.toString(i) + " j = " + Integer.toString(j) + "/n" +
                                "lbHb[0] = " + Byte.toString(lbHb[0]) + "lbHb[1] = " + Byte.toString(lbHb[1]) );
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: у вас проблема в генерации ключа, пары (11, 1) и (1, 11) дают одинаковую строку 111, и т.п.

Comment: @zRrr, гениально, спасибо вам огромное, теперь понятно почему у меня с ключом `String` проблемы, а с Integer все норм. Надо будет мне по тренировать свое внимание. Еще раз спасибо вам большое за помощь.

Answer (score 3):

Смысл `Hashtable` в том, что временная сложность операций добавления, удаления, поиска в среднем требуют O(1). При вставке в хеш-таблицу размером 365 ячеек всего лишь 23-х элементов вероятность коллизии уже превысит 50%. По этому как правило существуют механизмы разрешения коллизий. Я не в курсе что за задачу вы решаете, по этому не могу сказать, правильную ли вы выбрали структуру данных. Могу вам порекомендовать почитать про структуры данных.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Я читал про структуры, понял что они `HashMap` используется чтобы разбить большой объем данных на группы`LinkedList-ы`, тем самым упрощая задачу поиска данных.        Я читал про эти механизмы преодоления коллизий, но они сводятся к переписыванию методов `HashCode` и `Equals` . Тут сразу появляется 2 вопроса почему нельзя было сразу создать правильную без коллизий структуру  `HashMap`?

Comment: И зачем использовать структуру, в которой ты заранее знаешь, что с 1% вероятностью возможна коллизия, а значит программа автоматически становиться не надежной, не проще использовать другие структуры которые имеют 100% надежность ?

Comment: Что вы понимаете под "коллизиями"? В рамках `HashMap` коллизия - это когда у двух ключей одинаковый хэш. Коллизия замедляет доступ к данным, сохранённым по этим ключам, но сами данные сохраняются. Самое страшное, что может произойти - это замедление доступа к данным до O(n), что возможно только если у всех ключей одинаковый хэш. Вы же пишете о `HashMap` как о "ненадёжном" хранилище, и создаётся впечатление, что у вас там пропадают данные. Добавьте в вопрос код, которым вы добавляете данные и проверяете их на "коллизии", чтобы ваша проблема была понятнее.

Comment: Настоящая задача `HashMap` - это не "разбиение" данных, а хранение их в виде пар "ключ -> значение" и быстрый поиск таких пар. Если по одному ключу несколько раз записываются значения, сохраняется только последнее. Но это не признак "ненадёжности" структуры, это её прямое предназначение, описанное в документации.

Comment: @fori1ton, большое спасибо за ответ. Честно говоря я думал что коллизия это когда одно значение к примеру "1" под одним ключом записываешь, а другое "2" под другим ключом. И так получилось что хэш коды этих ключей стали одинаковыми. В результате компилятор случайным образом выбирает одно из них. К примеру под ключом "first" я хочу получить 1, а он мне (т.к. хэш коды совпали) выдает 2 (которые имеет другой ключ "second"). Разве ни это называется коллизией ?

Comment: У меня именно такая проблема. (Добавил более подробный код с записью и чтением значения, а также как я проверял свою  структуру `HashMap` на коллизии)

Comment: @foxis, по вашему тестовому коду я не нашёл никаких коллизий в ключах. Конечно, с учётом того, что я ничего не знаю про `Data2BytesCell`, и в качестве значений использовал те же ключи.

Comment: @PinkTux, спасибо за ответ.  По ключу `Integer` у меня работает все нормально. А вот когда я делаю ключ типа `String` тут появляются не состыковки, которые я указывал ранее.   `Data2BytesCell` простенький объект с 2 мя переменными типа `Byte`, которые можно извлекать и записывать.

Answer (score 1):

Тестируем ваш же код проверки на коллизии. Немного упростив его:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HashMap<Integer, Integer> mDataBase = new HashMap<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 256; j++) {
                int key = i * 256 + j;
                mDataBase.put(key, key);
            }
        }

        int errors = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 256; j++) {
                int key = i * 256 + j, expect = key;
                int val = mDataBase.get(key);
                if (val != expect) {
                    errors++;
                    System.out.format("Error: key %s, expect %d, got %d\n", key,
                            expect, val);
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.format("Errors: %d\n", errors);
    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
Errors: 0
```

И ничего не меняется, если ключ делать по вашему рецепту.